# Magento 2 show Terms and Conditions at the time of Registration

Tags: magento-2.1, plugin, registration, terms-and-conditions

Is there a way or I want a plugin that allows showing Terms and Conditions and Privacy and Policies showing Separate checkboxes so Customers have to check both checkboxes and complete the registration.

I have Magento CE 2.1.11 installed may need to change theme couple of times on the request of client so setting it into theme might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

`data-validate="{required:true}"` will do the trick

```
<div class="field choice newsletter">
        <label for="custom-terms" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Do you agree ?') ?></span></label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-validate="{required:true}" name="custom-terms" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Terms and contitions') ?>" id="register-input-custom" class="checkbox">
    </div>
```